# Use Css modules add conditional transition styling to my side navigation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I would like to add some transition styling to my side navigation on my app. I am able to do this using normal classes however in this tutorial they use css modules and i am unsure how to do this using css modules.

I would like my nav to glide in and out, at the moment it jumps statically when the onClick function fires - `toggleSideDrawer`.

I have used this logic but I am not sure if it is doing anything:

```
className={props.toggleSideDrawer ? classes.SideDrawerOpen : classes.SideDrawer
```

Essentially i want that when the user clicks the toggle, the `transform` property switches from `translateX(-100%)` to `translateX(0)` but this is not happening.

Side nav code:

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "../../Logo/Logo";
import NavigationItems from "../NavigationItems/NavigationItems";
import Backdrop from "../../UI/Backdrop/Backdrop";
import Aux from "../../../hoc/Aux";

import classes from "./SideDrawer.css";

const SideDrawer = props => {
  return (
    <Aux classname={classes.SideDrawer}>
      <Backdrop
        showBackdrop={props.showSideDrawer}
        clicked={props.toggleSideDrawer}
      />
      {props.showSideDrawer && (
        <div
          onClick={props.toggleSideDrawer}
          className={
            props.toggleSideDrawer ? classes.SideDrawerOpen : classes.SideDrawer
          }
        >
          <div className={classes.Logo}>
            <Logo />
          </div>

          <nav>
            <NavigationItems />
          </nav>
        </div>
      )}
    </Aux>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Where the code is used in my Layout component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Aux from "../Aux";

import classes from "./Layout.css";
import Toolbar from "../../components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar";
import SideDrawer from "../../components/Navigation/SideDrawer/SideDrawer";

const layout = props => {
  const [showSideDrawer, setShowSideDrawer] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Aux>
      <SideDrawer
        showSideDrawer={showSideDrawer}
        toggleSideDrawer={() => {
          setShowSideDrawer(!showSideDrawer);
        }}
      />
      <Toolbar
        onMenuClick={() => {
          setShowSideDrawer(!showSideDrawer);
        }}
      />
      <main className={classes.mainContent}> {props.children} </main>
    </Aux>
  );
};
export default layout;
```

CSS:

```css
.SideDrawer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 280px;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .SideDrawer {
    display: none;
  }
}

.Logo {
  height: 11%;
  text-align: center;
}
.SideDrawerOpen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 280px;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: is the element actually being rendered in the dom?

Comment: Hello yes it is, when trigger my on click the side menu pops out with a red background ( I added red so i know its the right class being added). However the transition of ease in-out does not work strangely :S

Comment: Hello @AngelaInniss you have to rename your css file to `SideDrawer.module.css` in order to use css modules here is a link:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: If you try to inspect this element, is the `SideDrawerOpen` class styles are disabled ?

Comment: @alan_jouhar  yes they are, the transform and transition class styles are disabled :S

Comment: I think this comment was for @AhmadShaarawi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you need the element will has the `transition` rule **all the time**.

My suggestion is to set a static class which which will hold all the styles and addd **another one** only for overriding `transform` to make it move.

Something like that (it uses scss but it's easy to do it with css)

```css
.SideDrawer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 280px;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transform: translateX(-100%);

  &.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [showSideDrawer, setShowSideDrawer] = useState(false);
  const sidebarClasses = classname([
    styles.SideDrawer,
    {
      [styles.show]: showSideDrawer
    }
  ]);
  const ToggleSidebar = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setShowSideDrawer(!showSideDrawer)}>
        Toggle Sidebar
      </button>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <div className={sidebarClasses}>
        <div>Sidebar content</div>
        <ToggleSidebar />
      </div>
      <ToggleSidebar />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-framework-04sbe?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: Thank you @Mosh Feu I will have a go and see if I can do what you have done. One of my issues was that I wasn't sure how to write the conditional styles with the modules but I see you have done it using an array for the styles.

Comment: Hello I tried this and yes I am stuck as to how to do it using css modules i.e how to write the logic for the `& show` The way you have done it is how I would usually do it with scss with the `&`...

Comment: You mean that the question is how to do it with pure css, not scss?

Comment: @Most Feu yes i've been playing around. I have found a way to add a conditional class onto my code however the css still doesn't work. I will create a codesandbox

Comment: I've updated the example and it's working well with pure css. Please take a look..

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have taken a look and I see that figured out the same code for the CSS classes as you, which is good. The only part now that my  iDE does not like is `[styles.show]: showSideDrawer` . What is this part of the code actually doing??  For me I have the functionality of the `toggleSideDrawer` function in a Higher component so I cannot reference it like you have as `showSideDrawer` see my code above.

Comment: This part is ["computed properties"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). I'm using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library to manage the classes in easier way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212177/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-angela-inniss).

Answer (score 0):

@MoshFeu helped me fix this.

The problem is that you render the drawer only when showSideDrawer so before it becomes true, the sidebar is not in the DOM yet so the transition is not affecting it.

The solution is to keep it in the DOM all the time but toggle . Open class to change the style.

There are libraries that knows to make the transition works even for elements that are not in the DOM but it's a bit more complicated.

code fix for SideDrawer.js without the conditional within the `return`

```
class SideDrawer extends Component {
  render() {
    let sideDrawerClass = [classes.SideDrawer];
    // SideDrawer will now be an array  with the side drawer classes and the open class
    if (this.props.showSideDrawer) {
      sideDrawerClass.push(classes.Open);
    }
    return (
      <Aux classname={classes.SideDrawer}>
        <Backdrop
          showBackdrop={this.props.showSideDrawer}
          clicked={this.props.toggleSideDrawer}
        />
        <div
          className={sideDrawerClass.join(" ")}
          onClick={this.props.toggleSideDrawer}
        >
          <div className={classes.Logo}>
            <Logo />
          </div>

          <nav>
            <NavigationItems />
          </nav>
        </div>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default SideDrawer;
```